# Django setup url parameter for certain requests only

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I'm trying to setup my Django view such that when they POST to an endpoint they don't need an url parameters, but when they call GET they require it

```
path('posts/', views.PostView.as_view(), name="post"),
path('posts/<int:count>/', views.PostView.as_view(), name="post"),
```

The issue with this is that it makes swagger messy and swagger with assume that url/posts/ you can POST and GET from, and url/posts// you can as well, but I only want to be able to POST to the first and GET from the 2nd. Is there a way to do this without creating separate view classes for them? Or is it better practice in this case to create separate view classes?

Comment: you should split `POST` and `GET`

Comment: also - this is a swagger thing not DRF. and you are looking for DRF ACTION

Comment: Share your `PostView` view

Comment: Django doesn't match the urls based on methods, only the path in HTTP Request, so you need to separate them with different URLs.